# Access different IP on same network

Tags: subnet

I have a device which has a static IP that cannot be changed permanently (192.168.1.4). My network is on a different range 10.0.0.xx. Is there a way rather than connecting the device directly to the Ethernet port of my computer to access ii from the network? I have a router which is quite sophisticated (Asus GTAX11000) but, not knowing enough about networking, I am not sure if there is some setting there that may be useful for this scope.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Does the device have any "gateway" address configured?

Comment: I don't think so. It is a Ethernet relay https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-EmmJZlkIXQ . I did try to plug it straight into th etc ethernet but even though I am unable to connect to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two separate issues here:

1. Whether the devices *can* talk directly through the ethernet,
2. and whether they *know* that they can talk directly.

The first one is easy – if your computer is connected to the router's integrated LAN switch, everything else connected to the LAN switch can be reached *the same way* as if it were connected directly to your computer. As long as the computer sends packets to the device's MAC address they'll go straight to the device, bypassing the router proper.

The second issue depends on IP address configuration – your computer's own IP address together with the netmask is used to determine whether a destination is "local"; local devices will be contacted directly through the ethernet, while non-local packets are sent to the gateway (which itself has to be local).

Generally the simplest way to make your computer think 192.168.1.5 is local is to change your IP address to 192.168.1.4 or similar (with the usual netmask of 255.255.255.0). This will work regardless of the router's LAN configuration – as mentioned, packets sent to local MAC addresses will bypass the router anyway.

It's also possible to configure *both* an 10.0.0.x and an 192.168.1.x addresses on your computer, making the same Ethernet interface a member of both subnets at the same time (as they share the physical ethernet anyway). Windows allows this through the "TCP/IP > Advanced" window, but only if DHCP is disabled (i.e. both addresses must be static).

---

Other than reconfiguring the computer, it would also be possible to have *the router* relay packets between the two subnets (which is exactly what a router does anyway), regardless of them being on the same ethernet or not, but from reading your router's PDF manual seems that it doesn't have the option to configure multiple subnets on the same interface (all of its sophistication is towards a different direction).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.